# Ejabberd and jwchat configuration

Tags: ejabberd

On Leap 15, I have installed the latest version of ejabberd, and have tried to install jwchat. But ejabberd now uses yml files, and none of the jwchat tutorials use yml files, but I have tried to make the connection. 
My question is what in the setup (using ejabberd as the server, and not apache) determines the web url for the chat? site:5280/web/jwchat/index.html gives me a 404.
Some tutorials have a line that I think would translate at
"/web": mod_http_fileserver
but this does not seem to matter. Since jwchat is in /var/lib/ejabberd/www/jwchat, where does the "web" in the URL come from? 
I get nothing in the webaccess.log file, and the main log file says it accepts my connection to 5280.
How do I get jwchat to serve pages?

Answer (score 0):

With this example configuration:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/jjj": mod_http_fileserver

modules:
  mod_http_fileserver:
    docroot: "/var/lib/ejabberd/www/jwchat"
```

Let's imagine you have installed JWChat in the path you mentioned. Then, the local file at location

> /var/lib/ejabberd/www/jwchat/index.html

will be provided when you visit the URL:

> http://localhost:5280/jjj/index.html

Comment: Thank you, thank you. It would be great if there were some comments in the yml file about this. But, it is still not quite working. I have it on a host with a dynamic dns address. If I add its internal ip address to the yml file, and use

Comment: But, it is still not quite working. I can log in, and the windows pop up. But I do not see any of the people using xmpp clients. Nor do I see buddies. Using pidgin, I did not have to "add" them to see them. All users are visible to everyone. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I tried both bind and polling, but still no window content. I also tried adding users, but they get no authorization requests.

Comment: Now I get service unavailable message in the pop up window. Do I need to comment out the ejabberd_service stanza in ejabberd.yml? If so, how should it be configured for jwchat?

Comment: The docs say "If HTTP Polling is enabled, it will be available at http://server:port/http-poll/. " So in this case, how does one access the jwchat pages? localhost:5280/http-poll/web/index.html does not work.